# Iptables command to check whether rule exists at specific line number

Tags: linux, iptables

Is there a way we can check whether an iptable rule exists at specific position?

something like below:

```
iptables -C INPUT 1 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Have you had a look at `iptables -L INPUT -v -n --line-n`  output?  You can also use `iptables-save` command which will provide a better view for what you want.

Comment: similar issue addressed here: https://superuser.com/questions/360094/how-can-i-check-if-an-iptables-rule-already-exists

Comment: with -C i can give the complete rule to check. 
But with `iptables -L INPUT -v -n --line-n` output i further need to parse the output by doing grep/sed. Is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm genuinely curious to know the use case for such a check.

Anyways you might use `iptables -S` command, which allows to indicate a rule-number.

Then it would depend on where you'd need to use the check result.

For your sample case you might for instance do:

```bash
iptables -S INPUT 1 | grep -ce '-j ACCEPT'
```

to get a `1` printed by `grep -c` (or `0` if no match).

Or in a shell, a test could be like:

```bash
[ "$(iptables -S INPUT 1)" = '-A INPUT -j ACCEPT' ]
```

assuming you know precisely the rule you want to check. Else you can use the `[[` test with `=~` operator, if your shell supports them, to look for a regexp matching that rule-number.

Comment: This will work for me thanks. My use case is multiple processes will be writing different rules into chain, and my process has to make sure that particular rule is always on top.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing the output of `iptables -L --line-numbers` shouldn't be that bad:

```
num=3
if iptables -L foo --line-numbers | grep -qe "^$num "; then
    echo "rule exists at line #$num"
else
    echo "no rule at line #$num"
fi
```

That said, I'm not sure how useful that is, since e.g. deleting rules from the start of the chain changes the numbers of other rules, so they don't work as unique identifiers or such. You could just as well take the count of rules in the chain (`iptables -L foo --line-numbers | sed -ne '$s/ .*//p'`) and compare against that.

<sub>Jokingly, one could run `iptables -D foo "$num"`. It complains if there's no rule at at number `$num`, but of course it's also destructive...</sub>